# Android how to split between two textview the full width of screen exactly fifty fifty percent?

Tags: android, textview, screen

I have two TextView in a RelativeLayout. 
How to set the TextViews if I want those always (different screen resolution for example 540x960) the width of each TextView is the 50 percent of the full UI width? I would set size of both TextView to always 50 percent of full width of UI. Need to stretching of TextViews on different screen resolutions.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

Whenever split some view like (Button , Text View) in equally in **Horizontal** / **Vertical**

**android:weight Sum** / **android:layout_weight** Technique use...

Must remember one thing these technique must support in **Linear Layout** only but here you want to use **Relative Layout** so that simply put your **Linear Layout** inside **Relative Layout** ..

Must Follow These Rules :

1> set 
**android:weight Sum**  into your **Linear Layout**

2> set **android:layout_width** each child View inside **"0dp"**

3> set **android:layout_weight** each child View depend upon how many child view  & **android:weight Sum**(e.g: android:weight Sum = "2" & two child view then layout_weight="1" , layout_weight="1")

Ex:

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="child View 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="child View 2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

if Layout Orientation is **Vertical** then only set **android:layout_height** is **"0dp"** instead of **android:layout_width**

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 8):

You can try using weight with creating an linear layout in your relative layout then set the `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and the `android:weightSum = 2` and the `android:orientation="horizontal"`, after that place the textview inside the linear layout and set the weight of each textview 1.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum = "2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:text = "YOUR FIRST TEXT"
                android:weight = "1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                 android:text = "YOUR SECOND TEXT"
                android:weight = "1"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the weight sum will be used to measured the portion of the textview like if you give the weight sum 3 and give 1 textview weight = 2 and another textview weight = 1 the layout will be 2/3 (66.666%) and 1/3 (33.3333%) so if you set it 2 and give every textview weight = 1 it should be 50% and 50%

It works for me, if you have any question feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: This is works perfectly with one line (/linear layout)/ how does it works with more lines?

Comment: If I use more linearlayouts id does not work because the first text hide the second text

Comment: you can use the same method just add another linearlayout and set the layout above or layout below or if you can change the relative layout to a linearlayout it'll be more easier for you :)

Comment: Hi
Here is my solution, you can see here <www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/android/mysolution_of_android_ui.pdf>

Comment: `layout_width`s of textviews should be `"0dp"`. This will work, but not if combined with other view types or non-equal ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `layout_width` to `fill_parent` for both `TextView`s and  give them the same `layout_weight` like `1.0` and that should do it (or not give either one a `layout_weight`).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
 orientation = "horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "Text 1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "Text 2"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The fill-parent is very important, basically with weights you need to get the child layouts to fight for space, and let the weights make the decision :)